# How to check cursor is moved outside map in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

How to check cursor is moved outside the map in mapbox?
I want an event that will check cursor is moved outside the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [mouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) event.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: [-74.5, 40],
    zoom: 9
});

var mouseTarget = document.getElementById('map');
mouseTarget.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    console.log('mouseleave');
});
```